# SQL filter by two date columns in the same month

Tags: sql, date, datetime, google-bigquery, where-clause

In my dataset I have column A and column B, they have different dates, sometimes one column has a date and the other don't, sometimes both have values but different months. I want to filter by the date when they are in the January.
I want both columns to have date of January '2023-01-01'

I started with

```
SELECT *  
FROM table  
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(SAFE_CAST(column_a AS DATE), MONTH) = '2023-01-01' 
OR DATE_TRUNC(column_b, MONTH) = '2023-01-01'
```

The problem is that in some cases the column_a has a date prior January due to the or. And both dates need to be in the some month.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Is this a trick question?  You want **both** column_a **AND** column_b to both have that date simultaneously?  Use an AND operator, not an OR.

Comment: No at all haha. Not the same date, just the same month, thats why the Date_trunc. If I use the AND I only get rows where both columns are in 2023-01-01. But I want every row of column_a that is in january and every row of column_b that is in january.

Comment: Use EXTRACT and say the month of both date A and of date B must be January, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions?hl=en

Comment: Specifically, `Extract(Month from column_a)=1 AND Extract(Month from column_b)=1`